# Hide high value chips

Tags: rules

I get it is totally unethical.

Can you hide high value chips in the bottom of a stack out of view?

Comment: It will all depend on the tournament type you play. There is at least one page which aims to create a uniform ruling for tournaments talking at this respect. See this page http://www.pokertda.com/view-poker-tda-rules/ item 23 sub-item B.

Comment: (this question deserves more upvotes)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Must be visible at all times, you can get a penalty for hiding them. You'll get a warning normally first but you will get a penalty if you keep hiding them in most places. In general I'll ask a player once to move their large chips out in front of their stack, after that I'll call floor if they don't.

You as a player have the entitlement to know what size stack you're against, just as much as the other players have that same entitlement. Not exact size, but a solid estimate, i.e. if you're stack is 200,000 but someone counts 190,000 fine. But imagine you had say 8 or 10 25k chips behind that stack, that's not fair to the other player. By hiding your higher value chips you're potentially unfairly effecting someone's decision.

Adding direct links to rules:

[WSOP rule 106](https://www.wsop.com/2022/2023-WSOP-Tournament-Rules.pdf)

[TDA rule 25](https://www.pokertda.com/view-poker-tda-rules/)

Comment: (this answer deserves more upvotes)

Answer (score -5):

Hiding the money is just as ethical as it is legal. Lol imagine someone saying “its not fair” to not see someone’s stack. So you want me to make it both easy and fair for u to win MY money?  Call the floor as much as you want buddy, unless it’s a WRITTEN rule then suck it up and play. If you’re not bluffing and have a good hand then knowing the stack doesn’t effect anything. You wanna know how much I have? pay attention to my buy in and then keep track of how much i’ve been winning and losing. This isn’t a game based on fairness, it’s gambling to win money.

What’s not ethical about it? I’m playing a game of strategy so if you wanna beat me you must out strategize me which means keeping count of my money, tracking my game play and expressions, etc etc.

Good poker players don’t care how much u have.

I just won a tournament the other day, hid my money, didn’t say a word the whole game and still took everyone’s money. Excuses excuses excuses is all I hear from players who are losing. Also, every time u tell someone ur stack they either go all in or fold. Does that sound logical to tell someone how much u have knowing it might lead to u losing all of it. We’re not playing for fun and with beans, we’re playing for money and to win.

Comment: This answer is just wrong. It's not a case of it only being fair, it is also a written rule in the major rulesets. TDA rule 25, WSOP rule 106. This answer is incorrect and will set you up for a penalty. Given the vast majority of card clubs and casinos use the TDA or WSOP rulesets or a variation of these, it's best to just avoid this situation and show your chips correctly as written in the rules.

Comment: WSOP ruleset https://www.wsop.com/2022/2023-WSOP-Tournament-Rules.pdf - Rule 106

Comment: TDA ruleset https://www.pokertda.com/view-poker-tda-rules/ - Rule 25

Comment: "*Good poker players don’t care how much u have.*: actually, good players *care* about the others' chips and **know** how important it is to care about that. If every single hand you're in a player asks you (then the floor) how many chips you have, you'll have to count them. Again and again. From there, either you keep your stack countable, or you'll soon get a warning then a penalty. Because you don't respect the rules, you show unsporstmanlike attitude, and delay the game.